# Как обрезать края "ленточки" у карточки товара?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Использую bootstrap3. Пробую для карточки с товаром сделать ленточку. Но как скрыть края, которые сильно выступают?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700');
.corner-ribbon {
  width: 200px;
  background: #e43;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.corner-ribbon.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.corner-ribbon.top-right {
  top: 25px;
  right: -50px;
  left: auto;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.corner-ribbon.blue {
  background: #39d;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<br>
<br>

<div class="col-sm-6 rabbit breed_1 gender_1 color_1 cost_100-150 weight_1250 type_1 type_3">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="" alt="...">
    <div class="corner-ribbon top-right sticky blue">Test</div>
    <div class="caption">
      <h3><span title="Имя">Имя</span>&nbsp;<small title="">доп имя</small></h3>
      <p>
        <span class="label label-primary" title="">енп</span>
        <span class="label label-default" title="">апр</span>
        <span class="label label-info" title="">апр</span>
        <span class="label label-warning" title="">апрпарпа</span>
        <span class="label label-warning" title="">арап</span>
      </p>
      <p class="text-justify">Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции способствует подготовки и реализации дальнейших направлений развития. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что новая модель организационной деятельности
        в значительной степени обуславливает создание соответствующий условий активизации.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно обрезать содержимое внутри элемента по его границам с помощью `overflow: hidden;`:

```
.img-thumbnail, .thumbnail{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```